# How to concatenate passed values from PHP to AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to concatenate all the values of `showFname`, `showMname`, `showLname` and show the result on `showName`.

My problem is the concatenated names won't show in my `showName`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="showFname" name="showFname" />
<input type="text" id="showMname" name="showMname" />
<input type="text" id="showLname" name="showLname" /> 
<label id="showName"></label>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult');
    var showFname = $('#showFname');
    var showMname = $('#showMname');
    var showLname = $('#showLname');
    var showName = $('#showName');

    var countTimerShowInfo = setInterval(function(){
        showInfo(); 
        showName = showFname + showMname +showLname;  
    }, 500);

    function showInfo(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"files/view/profileInfo.php",
            type:"GET",
            data: { term : $('#emailCodeResult').val() },
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(result) {
                $("#showFname").val(result.per_fname);
                $("#showMname").val(result.per_mname);
                $("#showLname").val(result.per_lname);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use .text() to append text.Or simply u can use `html()` also.

```
$("#showname").text(showFname + showMname + showLname );
```

AND Important use....

```
function showInfo(){

var showFname = $('#showFname').val();
var showMname = $('#showMname').val();
var showLname = $('#showLname').val();

//ur code ......
}
```

Take variables inside function . In ur code , U get textbox value BLANK as its cached on Document Ready event as the page loads . So now scan updated values entered by user.Not on decument ready event.

Comment: it shows [object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: @user3856999 m check Updated answer

Comment: @user3856999 , did u use .val() ?

Comment: @user3856999 , oh sorry ,check answer now

Comment: @user3856999 , u took Blank values at start in variable. Take it on setTimeout using ur function . Check answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#showName').text(concatenatedNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to **get** and **set** the value of the labels with the **text()** or **html()** function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var  $emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult');
var showFname = $('#showFname').val();
var showMname = $('#showMname').val();
var showLname = $('#showLname').val();
var showName = $('#showName');

function showInfo(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"files/view/profileInfo.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#emailCodeResult').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        $("#showFname").val(result.per_fname);
        $("#showMname").val(result.per_mname);
        $("#showLname").val(result.per_lname);
        showName.html(showFname + showMname +showLname); 
        }

    });

};

setInterval( showInfo(), 500);

});
```

**UPDATE:**

there was a problem with your `setInterval` definition, fixed that, and also wrote the `showName.html()` inside the `showInfo()` function.

Comment: i tried ur code it wont work and now the inputs fname, mname and lname wont show to.

Comment: wow, sorry, my bad! I made a huge mistake and fixed it just now. try the code again, it should work

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is sum up the .val() of those elements and not the elements.

first you assign like this:

```
var showFname = $('#showFname').val();
var showMname = $('#showMname').val();
var showLname = $('#showLname').val();
var showName = $('#showName').val();
```

then you add these up like this:

```
 showName = showFname + showMname +showLname;
```

Comment: You should use .val(); to get value of textbox , OP is wrong , did u just copy OP ? please correct